# Github account recovery stuck

Tags: github, password-recovery

I am using google authenticator for github 2FA code. My scenario is as follow

1. I can enter my password.
2. Google authenticator is gone after lost my phone. So I cannot type 2FA.
3. I choose `Use a recovery code or request a reset`.
4. I don't have recovery code and I choose `Locked out? Try recovering your account`.
5. Step 1: I do `Verify an email associated with this account`.
6. Step 2: I try `Verify a device, SSH key or personal access token`, I got the situation as follow.
   [image: Step 2]

I cannot choose any options in Step 2. The options are disable. I would like to know why this is happened. And I would like to get suggest to get out of this stuck. I would like to know directly mail contact for github support. I am asking in here because I cannot login to ask in support.github.com.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't GitHub support

Comment: *"cannot login to ask in support.github.com"* Well, make a second account to contact support. Or try a different browser first, maybe that'll help.

Comment: There is now (Oct. 2022) an [improved account recovery flow in case of a lost 2FA device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309).